# Disable access from url

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I wanna make custom post type "portfolio". So I had this code in args:

```
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'blabla', 'blabla' ),
    'description'         => __( 'blabla', 'blabla' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'taxonomies'          => 'category',
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => false,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-format-gallery',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => false,
    'query_var'           => 'portfolio',
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);
```

So everything is great but I wanna display portfolio items only at home page from php. After creating new portfolio item I can access it by link which Wordpress generates for me, but I want to disable this ability for all users. If it possible without redirects.

Comment: What have you already tried?  What isn't working?  What Wordpress theme are you using?  Please provide all relevant details.

Comment: I'm using my custom theme. Can't find information about this. I set argument publicly_queryable to false and it still didn't work.

Comment: if you or internal people who are allowed to view think link manually, you can drop in a .htaccess file which is authenticated, that's very secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

`'exclude_from_search' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => false,`

might do the trick. Don't forget to flush rewrite rules.

If you also don't want to have access to a single portfolio item page, add this:

`'query_var' => false,`

and, probably, you'll want to remove archives support as well or even setting

`'rewrite' => false,`